# Halcon - Generate new pose based on 2 poses

Tags: intersection, halcon, pose

I have 2 Parallel poses with different origins and different X axis directions (Y is parallel):

- First pose is my ground plane. X is horizontal, Y is vertical, Z is depth.
- Second pose, is somewhere above the first pose floating in the room, with the Y Axis parallel to the first pose's Y axis.. X and Z can be rotated along the Y axis...

What I need, is a third pose that is The second pose, but lowered onto the first pose, so that Y0 of the third pose is the same as the Y0 of the first pose.

I am going crazy about this, cant figure out how to do it.
any help appreciated...

**EDIT: I have updated the question to simplify the problem a little bit.**

Comment: Is the difference (pose) between the origins known? 
* Ground plane
create_pose (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Rp+T', 'gba', 'point', Ground_plane)
* Floating object (Pose above ground plane, y-axis is parallel to ground plane's y-axis (x, z are turned away))
create_pose (0, 0, 100, 0, 42, 0, 'Rp+T', 'gba', 'point', Second_pose)
* Get z-axis distance
z_dist := Second_pose[2] - Ground_plane[2]
* Copy parallel pose
Third_pose := Second_pose
* Edit z-value
Third_pose[2] := Third_pose[2] - z_dist
* Shouldn't the only thing to add now be the difference between the origins?